# Count based on left characters?

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID       Location
1        AAA123
1        AAA133
1        AAA832
1        BBB929
1        BBB420
```

How can I count and group by the first 3 chars so that the result looks like this:

```
ID      AAA_Count      BBB_count
1       3               2
```

I tried something like this:

```
select [ID], Location,
case when left(location, 3) = 'AAA' then count(location) end as 'AAA',
case when left(location, 3) = 'BBB' then count(location) end as 'BBB',
from Table
group by [ID], left(location, 3)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: always specify the version of software and server your are using.

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
select [ID], 
count(case when left(location, 3) = 'AAA' then 1 end) as [AAA],
count(case when left(location, 3) = 'BBB' then 1 end) as [BBB]
from Table
group by [ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a row based solution instead of column based solution, you can use:

```
Select ID, left(location, 3) as Chars, count(1) as Counts 
from Table group by ID, left(location, 3);
```